# Typescript or Javascript: searching for multiple words

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

`const arr = ['hello', 'test', 'two words']`

`const string = 'this is two test words'`

what i try to achieve is to check if this two words 'two words' in `arr` comes back in the string even if they are not behind each other. Also in any order but both words must be exist.

how can I achieve that?

Comment: Either split and look at each one or turn it into reg exp or do any other things.

Answer (score 2):

Here a possible approach using [test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) that returns **true** or **false** and  [new RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp). **But this does not cover if words are in different order**.

```js
const arr = ['hello', 'test', 'two words']

const string = 'this is two test words';

arr.forEach(o=>{

let r = new RegExp(o.replace(" ",".*"),"g");

console.log(r.test(string));

})
```

More powerful way. To check the words in **any order** we could compare two arrays using indexOf():

```js
const arr = ['hello', 'test', 'two words']

const string = 'this is words two test';//<-- "words two" different order

var newarr2 = string.split(" ");

var newarr =  arr.map(o=>o.split(" "));

function flatten(arr) {
    return arr.reduce(function (flat, toFlatten) {
      return flat.concat(Array.isArray(toFlatten) ? flatten(toFlatten) : toFlatten);
    }, []);
  }

  newarr = flatten(newarr);

  newarr.forEach(o=>{
      console.log(o+" ---> "+(newarr2.indexOf(o) != -1))
  })
```

Comment: in the powerful way if i remove for example the word ' two' , it gives true back for the word 'words'. actually the both words must be exist.

Comment: @Momen in that case is better the first way, or Gregory answer. Or perform a check or a flag.

Comment: @Momen my way has one iteration

Answer (score 2):

```
const arr = ['hello', 'test', 'two words']
const string = 'this is two test words'

let regexpedArray = arr
  .map(w => new RegExp(w.replace(' ', '.*')))
  .forEach((val, i) => console.log(`${val.test(string)} for the value ${arr[i]}`))
```

The result would look like:

```
"false for the value hello"
"true for the value test"
"true for the value two words"
```

Comment: The only bug in this code is that if a word in the string have the same character in the same order for example 'testjww', it give true back.